# gcd: control number of parallel tasks

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Using grand central dispatch, is there a way to control the number of tasks that run concurrently? Meaning, I want to use dispatch_async, call it, say, 100 times, but only have at most, say, 4 tasks running concurrently. If two of the four tasks were to finish simultaneously, then two more should start immediately. I've seen a suggestion to use a barrier dispatch after dispatching 4 tasks, but that will require all 4 tasks to finish, then the barrier, then more tasks - not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOperationQueue/maxConcurrentOperationCount) instead, and set its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` parameter to 4.

[Read about Operation Queues in the *Concurrency Programming Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1).